# Shift a whole block in an array

Tags: c, arrays, move

I was wondering if there is a possibility to shift a whole block in an array. I intend to delete one item in an array of dynamic length, and after I deleted it, I want the whole block to shift to the right. So far I do this element, by element, but this is not efficient. So I was wondering if there is a better solution.

Important: the order of the elements needs to be kept the same.

Comment: Please be more clear. If you must use an array, you have to edit element by element. Unless you want something else, then please specify exactly what do you expect from your data structure. Skip list or linked list, they have different complexity for different operations and implementation difficulty.

Comment: You can move data with `memmove` and then clear the content of the last element. But if your array is very large, consider using another data structure like a  linked list or an AVL / RB tree.

Comment: You may want to do a rotation for your array, if true and you can try to use `link-list` instead of array.

Comment: For shifting within an array use `memmove`, not `memcpy`. But yeah, there are many many other structures including skip lists, trees, blocklists and what not. The *other* uses of the data structure are needed to choose the appropriate data structure.

Comment: okay, I understand, to be more clear: I alloc some space for my array, I put data in it, and after a while i start deleting data. This happens based on TCP connections that close, after a deleted connection i want to shift everything behind this array to fill up the gap i created. So far I do the manipulation element by element. I loop through a for loop and take every element after the previous one, starting from the one I deleted and replace it. This works fine, but creates overhead. Is there a way to take all the elements behind the block and shift them all together? Is it more clear now?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, true, use `memmove` when the two ranges overlap.

Comment: @J.Joly that's *not detailed enough*. What is needed is how this data structure is created and how it needs to be accessed.

Comment: I have considered making a linked list or some other data structure, but this is impossible, due to the fact that i'm polling on connections with my server. But I will look if I can find something on 'memmove'. Thank you.

Comment: This data structure is created as just an array of x places. I access every element by using poll on the array and after something happens I iterate through it, to see on which element something is changed.

Comment: It's not "impossible", it's just a different set of overheads. You need to work out which is more efficient for your specific user case.

Comment: Why is it crucial to keep the items in order?  It is much simpler if you simply move the last item into the space occupied by the deleted item.  The TCP connections won't care whether they're processed in exactly the same order each time.  Assuming it does matter, then `memmove()` is the way to go — but think about whether a simpler solution is really feasible.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I did this, really efficient implementation. But i have a linked list next to this array, which keeps track of some information that is coupled to the place where it stands in the array, therefor it is hard and not wanted to change the order.

Comment: Knuth said "premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming".  It sounds like that might be applicable to what you've implemented.

Comment: @J.Joly: I think you should follow Jonathan's path. Move the tail into the gap and update the back-reference into the array in your extra structure. On the other hand, if you have already a linked list, for what you need the array at all? Please share also the relevant code with us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `memmove` will probably be more efficient than doing an element by element copy as then you can take advantage of the fact you're doing a bulk move rather than lots of little moves (and compilers often provide highly optimized `memmove` implementations), but that's about it. You *need* to move everything around in memory, so you're going to have to move it.

If you're doing this a lot with your arrays, it probably means you need a different data structure.

Comment: If you are shifting within the array be aware to use memmove instead of memcpy.

Comment: This works perfect! Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

You can use linked list instead of array. In linked list deleting is easy. You just have to point the next next elements.

Comment: I used linked lists before, made one myself, but due to the fact that I need to poll on server connections, I have to use an array.

Comment: @Constructor: It's not clear why you think it is necessary to discuss two different lists, or why it is necessary to give code.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler No, you misunderstood me. Why I think it should have discussion is on this: >

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Oh, copy didn't work. I mean the last sentence.

Comment: @Constructor: it's hard to answer fragmentary comments.  The question doesn't include code that shows what is in the array — it is something to do with TCP connections, so it might be IP addresses (IPv4 or IPv6 or both?) and port numbers.   That makes it hard to show code that manipulates the OP's data — and deleting items from singly or double linked lists is not rocket science.

Answer (score 0):

Use a ring buffer, like this:

```
unsigned idx;
int Buf[1024];

void EnterValue(int value)
{
   idx++;
   Buf[idx & 1023] = value;
}
int GetOldValue(unsigned age)
{
   assert(age<1024);
   return Buf[ (idx-age) & 1023 ];
}
```

Comment: It isn't clear how this helps.  Judging from the question (but with some reading between the lines), sometimes the entry to be deleted might be number 300, sometimes number 600.  How does the ring buffer help with that?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: You are right, the question is quite short and I thought a FIFO would go in the right direction...